# SVN (tortoise)- how to handle this situation?

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

i am working on project in `delphi 7` and `Tortoise svn` the project is a sort of a survey tool.
we are current starting development on a new version of it that would be `myproject 1.8` and in 2 months time we will start with `myproject 2.0`.

**Note** : we had inherited the already existing svn. so it not our design

**Scenario**:
I have just a single folder in my `c:\` that is `c:\project\myproject\` , we are a startup so we didnt start with the project, we started handling from `myproject 1.5`..but now `myproject 1.5` code has disapeared and turned in `myproject 1.6`..so when we started with `myproject 1.7` we made a folder `c:\project\myproject\NV1.6Code` and copied the whole code into that folder and started with `myproject 1.7`...now i have no idea how to maintain the sub versions like `myproject 1.7.1`, `myproject 1.7.2` or `` `myproject 1.6.4 `` in our current state.

Now we are just about to start with `myproject 1.8` and we do not know how to start with it in the subversion control
as then `myproject 2.0` will also come soon.

**Structure**:
Path : `C:\projects\myproject`

As you can see in the picture..the `NV1.6code` directory has version 1.6 code and all the directories outside are the version `1.7 code`..

**Not a Good Idea?**
i don thin this will be a good idea

**AIM**: How do i make the above mess proper?
please help me how do i make the best use of tortoise SVN in my case to maintain 
 version

1. `myproject version 1.6 ( then the subversion like 1.6.1 , 1.6.2, 1.6.3)`
2. `myproject version 1.7 ( then the subversion like 1.7.1 , 1.7.2, 1.7.3)`
3. `myproject version 1.8 ( then the subversion like 1.8.1 , 1.8.2, 1.8.3)`
4. `then the future version myproject version 2.0`

Comment: If you haven't read it yet, consider getting a copy of "[Pragmatic Version Control using Subversion](http://pragprog.com/book/svn/pragmatic-version-control-using-subversion)". It covers version branching, so it would give you some good background on this.

Comment: @JoeWhite : ok i will go though this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do this: using the branch or tag feature.

In general, I like using tag for specifying a release point and development continues on in a relatively linear fashion (1.6 goes to 1.7, 1.7 to 1.8, etc.)

However, if for some reason say you released 1.6 and main development went to 1.7, but you wanted to keep making small changes to 1.6 (like 1.6.1, 1.6.2, etc.) it may be beneficial to create a branch.

It's also perfectly fine to use both features together.

Comment: +1 for the idea, ok branch will be better for me? im a newbie in SVN other then just `commit` and `update`..so im aking lots.

Comment: I think using both would work out just fine (though using just branches is also a good solution). You can tag the release versions, but then make branches your developers can work on between different versions.

Comment: ok, now after going through some data..my first job is to make three main directories /tag /trunk  /branch  ...then i can put all my code in trunk..n then start creating branches like /branches/myprojec1.8 ?

Comment: "There *is one way* to do this: using the branch *and* tag feature" will be more correct form for our reality

Comment: true in practice, but it's possible to use both tools independently :P @PresleyDias yes, that's a reasonably good way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the branch and tag feature to overcome your problem. But keep in mind that crating a branch for each version really makes the work complicated and you cannot handle their changes. Keep in mind:

- Try to reduce the number of your branches. (usually 2 or 3 is enough in your project)
- For each released version, create a tag.
- Avoid having lots of branches in the source control without proper mechanisms to merge the changes back.
- If too much time is spent to merge your changes compared to the development time, there is something wrong with the structure of branches.
- If you decided to have a branch, do not postpone merges as far as you can. Any attempt to merge all changes of all branches simultaneously (big bang merges) should be prohibited.
- The team should not create many branches for no apparent reason.
- If any branch is created in the system (right or wrong), its changes should be merged back to its parent branch (if possible) when the work ends.
- The team members should not stop development activities while branching, merging, or building new base lines is in progress.
- Do NOT use branches to divide the development team members, instead of dividing the work they are performing.

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038674/managing-branches-in-subversion/8048132#8048132) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

[You should read the free SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) - specifically about branches.